# How to decode a URL in Portable Class Library (PCL)?

Tags: c#, windows-8, .net-4.0, windows-phone-7.1, portable-class-library

I'm looking for the equivalent of `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode()` method in Portable Class Library (PCL) that can target all the supported platforms (.Net 4.0+, WP 7.5+ and Windows 8+)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do:

```
var urlDecoded = Uri.UnescapeDataString(urlEncoded).Replace('+', ' ');
```